# How to draw grid line only in a circle using QGraphicsItem

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qgraphicsview, qgraphicsitem

Please forgive the poor English in advance.

hello! I am currently implementing view widget using QGraphicsView & QGraphicsItem.

Is there any way to draw gridlines only inside a circle?

Rectangles are fine, but trying to draw them inside a circle is a pain.

Below is sample code.

```
    for(int x = rect.left(); x <= rect.right(); ++x) {
        painter->drawLine(QPointF(x, rect.top()), QPointF(x, rect.bottom()));
    }

    for(int y = rect.top(); y <= rect.bottom(); ++y) {
        painter->drawLine(QPointF(rect.left(), y), QPointF(rect.right(), y));
    }
```

here is my current state --> [Current grid line result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jkNE8.png)

result what i want is looks like -->
[Reuslt example what I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pvrwr.png)

I don't want to show grid line out of circle bound.

If you have any good ideas, please reply.

thank you!

Comment: Loop starting from the center of the circle and move in the four direction, when you pass the radius you can break the cicles

Comment: tigronometry is the solution: calculate the position on the circle of any line parallel of X and Y axis then use them to draw lines

Comment: Aside from calculating the start and end point of each line manually using trigonometry, you can set the clipping to the circle, then the lines will be automatically clipped to it. Take a look here: https://forum.qt.io/topic/98443/how-to-draw-circle-with-line-pattern-using-qgraphicsscene/2

Comment: @AlexSveshnikov Thanks! However, it's not applicable to a situation where one QGraphicsItem uses paint() to draw a part with drawEllipse() and drawLine() is performed within that part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just a matter of tigronometry calculation. From the position on the X or Y axis you can calculate the angle to go to the point on the circle using arc sin and arc cosine. The code below should work

```
#include <math.h>

class Point
{
public:
    double X = 0.0;
    double Y = 0.0;
};

int main() 
{
    double radius = 10.0;
    double stepx = 2.0;
    double stepy = 2.0;
    
    int stepsInX = radius / stepx;
    int stepsInY = radius / stepy;

    // this is just for positive X (need another loop for negative X)
    for (int i = 0; i <= stepsInX; i++)
    {
        double angle = acos(i*stepx / radius);
        double y = radius * sin(angle);
        Point p1;
        p1.X = i * stepx;
        p1.Y = y;
        Point p2;
        p2.X = i * stepx;
        p2.Y = -y;
        drawLine(p1, p2);
    }
    // this is just for positive Y (need another loop for negative Y)
    for (int i = 0; i <= stepsInY; i++)
    {
        double angle = asin(i * stepy / radius);
        double x = radius * cos(angle);
        Point p1;
        p1.X = x;
        p1.Y = i * stepy;
        Point p2;
        p2.X = -x;
        p2.Y = i * stepy;
        drawLine(p1, p2);
    }
}

void drawLine(Point const& p1, Point const& p2)
{
    // your code to draw line here
}
```

Comment: It helped quite a lot!
I was able to draw the grid line I wanted by modifying `p1.x = i * x;` to `p1.x = x;` in the second `for` loop statement (drawing horizontal lines).
thank you very much!

Comment: @jlkacl1Q87idgafsamo sorry for the buggy code... I corrected it